# How can I securely get the client id for a Web Api resource server?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, jwt

I'm trying to implement a web API with separate Authorisation and Resource servers, and I've gone through Taiseer Joudeh's excellent tutorial on the subject (http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/)

In a nutshell, a resource server registers itself with the authorisation server to get a unique client id and encryption key, so that tokens issued for one resource server aren't valid for another.

However, the tutorial doesn't go into how a client app would go about getting a JWT token for a particular resource from the authorisation server. As far as I can see, the client app would need the unique id for the resource server in order to get the correctly encrypted token from the authorisation server.

Right now the only way I can think of would be for the resource server to expose an unsecured GET method that returns that Id, but that seems terribly insecure.

I'm working on the assumption that a client app requests a token from the authorisation server, which it stores and then uses to access the resource server, but I'm pretty new to the subject of WebApi2, so I guess I'm missing something here.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to achieve, but if your scenario involves different services with a centralized authentication endpoint, then i strongly suggest you to read more about how OAuth2 and OpenID work. Instead of settle those issue by yourself try looking for a complete and tested solution like [IdentityServer 3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/)

Comment: Well, the reason I'm doing this is because I'm learning about the topic. Unfortunately, while the majority of the resources I have found about OAuth2 agree on the general idea of a client contacting an authorisation server in order to obtain a token that can then be used by the client to consume the Api of a resource server, none of them go much into the specifics of implementing this. The best practical resource that I have found are Taiseer's blog posts, but, as I said, he doesn't mention this one point, so I was hoping that somebody here might be able to clarify this for me.